# Docker-compose unable to make cross container requests

Tags: docker-compose, kong

I'm having network issues running services in `docker-compose`. Essentially I'm just trying to make a get request through Kong to a simple Flask API I have setup. The docker-compose.yml is below 
version: "3.0"

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.4
    container_name: kong-database
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=kong
      - POSTGRES_DB=kong

  web:
    image: kong:latest
    container_name: kong
    environment:
      - DATABASE=postgres
      - KONG_PG_HOST=postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "443:8443"
      - "8001:8001"
      - "7946:7946"
      - "7946:7946/udp"
    links:
      - postgres

  ui:
    image: pgbi/kong-dashboard
    container_name: kong-dashboard
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  employeedb:
    build: test-api/
    restart: always
    ports:
       - "5002:5002"
```

I add the API to kong with the command `curl -i -X POST --url http://localhost:8001/apis/ --data name=employeedb --data upstream_url=http://localhost:5002 --data hosts=employeedb --data uris=/employees`. I've tried this with many combinations of inputs, including different names, passing in the Docker network IP and the name of the test-api as hostname for the upstreamurl. After adding the API to Kong I get

```
HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
Date: Tue, 11 Jul 2017 14:17:17 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Server: kong/0.10.3
```

Additionally I've gotten into the docker containers running `docker exec it <container-id> /bin/bash` and attempted to make curl requests to the expected flask endpoint. While on the container running the API I was able to make a sucessful call to both `localhost:5002/employees` as well as to `employeedb:5002/employees`. However when making it from the container running Kong I see

```
curl -iv -X GET --url 'http://employeedb:5002/employees'
* About to connect() to employeedb port 5002 (#0)
*   Trying X.X.X.X...
* Connection refused
* Failed connect to employeedb:5002; Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
```

Am I missing some sort of configuration that exposes the containers to one another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the `employeedb` container visible to kong by defining a `link` like you did with the PostgreSQL database. Just add it as an additional entry directly below `- postgres` and it should be reachable by Kong:

```
....
links:
  - postgres
  - employeedb

....
```